# Issue with toggling dd

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently I’m using `dt` and `dd` to display some data. What I’m doing here is initially set the `dd` to `display: none` and when the `dt` is clicked display the associate `dd`.

My HTML markup is

```
<dt >
       <h1>click here</h1>
</dt>
<dd style="display: none;">
       <h1> DD Data </h1>
</dd>

<dt >
       <h1>click here</h1>
</dt>
<dd style="display: none;">
       <h1> DD Data </h1>
</dd>
```

jQuery I'm using is

```
$('dt').live('click', function () {
var dd = $(this).next();

if (!dd.is(':animated')) {
    dd.slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
}
```

What I want to do now is to allow one dd to display at a time. When if there is one dd is displaying and if another dt is clicked, i want to close the currently opened dd and display the dd which associate with the clicked dt.

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('dt').live('click', function () {
    var nextDD = $(this).next('dd');
    $('dd').hide();
    nextDD.show();


});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ktYgB/

Comment: thanks for the reply.Actually I also wanted to hide the dd when its parent dt is clicked. That’s what my code currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('dt').live('click', function () {
  var dl = $(this).closest('dl');
  var dd = $(this).next();

  if (!dd.is(':animated')) {
    $('dd', dl).hide(); // hide all dd's first

    dd.slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
  }
});
```